# Для чего нужен commit, connection, cursor и close?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

Базовый пример [отсюда](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html)

```
import psycopg2

# Connect to an existing database
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres")

# Open a cursor to perform database operations
cur = conn.cursor()

# Execute a command: this creates a new table
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE test (id serial PRIMARY KEY, num integer, data varchar);")

# Pass data to fill a query placeholders and let Psycopg perform
# the correct conversion (no more SQL injections!)
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test (num, data) VALUES (%s, %s)",
...      (100, "abc'def"))

# Query the database and obtain data as Python objects
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM test;")
cur.fetchone()

# Make the changes to the database persistent
conn.commit()

# Close communication with the database
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Для каких нужд используется `cur.close()`, `conn.commit()`, `conn.close`? В чём их отличия?

Например `conn.commit()`, как указано в примере, применяет изменения. Но кажется логичнее, что за это будет отвечать курсор, потому как именно он является итератором по данным.

Comment: Как минимум транзакция относится ко всему соединению целиком и ко всем имеющимся курсорам, так что делать cursor.commit было бы несколько странно

Comment: @andreymal хорошо. Я напихал в БД 20000 записей при помощи 100 батчей. Нужно ли мне создавать новое соединение? А курсор? При этом, я считаю, что у меня будут ещё записи.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Судя по той же документации, правильный шаблон использования будет примерно такой:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(DSN)
try:

    with conn:
        with conn.cursor() as curs:
            curs.execute(SQL1)
    
    with conn:
        with conn.cursor() as curs:
            curs.execute(SQL2)

finally:
    conn.close()
```

Что тут имеется в виду.

- `connection` живёт столько, сколько нужно вам для ваших операций, если у вас операции с базой идут подряд - `connection` не надо закрывать и переоткрывать; но если вы поработали с базой, а потом у вас перерыв - вы, например, перемалываете какие-то данные и пока базу не пишете и не читаете, то `connection` лучше закрыть, чтобы она ушла в пул и другим процессам, работающим с базой, хватило этих самых `connection`; и да - `connection` лучше закрывать в конце работы с ней и делать это наверняка (через `try/finally`), чтобы точно освободить связанные с ней ресурсы
- `transaction` лучше создавать и закрывать с помощью блока `with conn:` - если не будет брошено исключение в течении работы блока `with`, то будет автоматически сделан `commit`, а если будет исключение - будет выполнен `rollback`; в одном блоке транзакции нужно объединять некий неразрывный блок работы с базой, который должен быть откачен целиком в случае неудачи, а в случае успешного завершения запись данных этого блока опять же должна представлять из себя в базе фрагмент данных, который ничего не поломает, будучи записанным в базу сам по себе
- `cursor` - похоже, в приведённом мной шаблоне использования это просто объект, который позволяет выполнять любые операции записи/чтения внутри одной транзакции и он сам закроется по окончании блока `with conn.cursor() as curs:`

Немного странно, что в приведённом вами примере без `with` курсор получается закрывается уже после `commit`, видимо, можно делать и так и так. Если курсор не закрывать самому, то он, видимо, остаётся открытым всё время существования `connection`. Но опять же, согласно документации, лучше курсор обязательно закрыть (и удобнее сделать это неявно с помощью блока `with`), чтобы он точно освободил какие-то ресурсы, которые на него выделены. Хотя, наверняка, закрытие `connection` и так освободит все ресурсы.

В общем, мне кажется, тут есть довольно большая свобода выбора шаблона, однако, блоки `with` позволяют более чётко разделить этапы работы программы с базой, если таковые этапы имеют место быть.

P.S. Конкретно по вашим вопросам отдельно:

> Я напихал в БД 20000 записей при помощи 100 батчей. Нужно ли мне
> создавать новое соединение?

Если вы работаете с базой непрерывно, то новое соединение создавать не нужно.

> А курсор? При этом, я считаю, что у меня будут ещё записи.

Опять же - это зависит от того, планируете ли вы держать и дальше открытым соединение, можно ли вашу работу записывать в базу по частям, и какой шаблон работы с базой вы выберете. При непрерывной работе с базой похоже можно открыть соединение и курсор один раз, а потом, при необходимости, делать коммиты после каждого куска выполненной работы (если она в вашем случае может быть записана в базу этими кусками и ничего при этом не поломается).

P.P.S. Отвечая на тему вопроса - в той же документации написано, что если не включен `autocommit mode`, при котором `connection` сам делает `commit` после каждой операции с курсором, то если не сделать после операций с курсором явный `commit` и при этом закрыть `connection`, то можно остаться в результате с `грязными данными` - состояние ваших данных в базе будет неопределённое (но это сильно зависит от конкретной базы данных), в худшем случае транзакция может вообще подвиснуть и залочить дальнейшие операции с базой до принудительной перезагрузки сервера БД. Нормальная БД в случае потери коннекшена, конечно, сделает `rollback`, но лучше до такого в любом случае не доводить.

Comment: Думаю, в одну строку `with` сработает: `with conn, conn.cursor() as curs: curs.execute(SQL1)`

Comment: _Немного странно, что в приведённом вами примере без with курсор получается закрывается уже после commit, видимо, можно делать и так и так._ - почему это странно? Вроде наоборот логично?

Answer (score 4):

В упрощенном виде:

- **connection** представляет *реальную* базу данных **на диске** вашего или другого компьютера.
- **cursor** — это объект **в памяти вашего компьютера** с методами для проведения SQL команд, хранения итогов их выполнения (например части таблицы или вьюшкы (view)) и методов доступа к ним.

Теперь к вашим вопросам:

1. Пока вы работаете с курсором, вы только «играетесь» (например вы только готовитесь что-то изменить в реальной базе данных). Без применения `connection.commit()` итоги вашей «игры» потеряете — они не запишутся в реальную базу данных.

   Нужно добавить, что когда вы только *читаете* из базы данных, этой команды не надо.
2. `cursor.close()` освобождает память, в которой вы «игрались».
3. `connection.close()` освобождает память, нужную для управления связью с базой данных. (Эта команда соответствует закрытию файла - «закрывает» базу данных.)

---

***Терминологическое примечание:***

Файлы *открываются* (open), но к базам данных **присоединяются** (connect).